# Compute $\int \frac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{\sin(\pi x/2)-a^2} \ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Let $a \in (0,1)$, I would like to integrate

$$\int_0^{x_{\downarrow}} \frac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{\sin(\pi x/2)-a^2} \ dx +\int_{x_{\uparrow}}^1 \frac{\sin(\pi x)^2}{\sin(\pi x/2)-a^2} \ dx. $$

Now $\sin(\pi x/2)$ is a monotonically increasing function from $0$ to $1$, therefore there exists a unique $x^*$ such that $\sin(\pi x^*/2) = a^2.$ Now $x^* \in (x_{\downarrow},x_{\uparrow})$ such that both of the above integrals are well-defined.

Here $x_{\downarrow}$ and $x_{\uparrow}$ are two values of which one is below $x^*.$

Comment: In math, any interval of the type $(x_1,x_1)$ is empty, i.e. it doesn't contain any element. So you're saying that $x^*$ doesn't exist!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Decompose the integrand as follows
$$\frac14\frac{\sin^2(2t)}{\sin t-a^2}
=(\sin t +a^2)(\cos^2 t-a^4)+\frac{a^4(1-a^4)}{\sin t -a^2}
$$

Comment: I see, the first summand is easy to integrate, I find the second one quite subtle.

Comment: For the second one, you can use Weierstrass substitution to compute $\int \frac{1}{c+\sin(t)} dt$ in general @Guido

Comment: @Guido - $$\int \frac1{\sin t -b}dt=\frac2{\sqrt{1-b^2} }\tanh^{-1}\frac{b \tan\frac t2-1}{\sqrt{1-b^2}}
$$

Comment: @Quanto This looks suspicious, as $tanh^{-1}$ only makes sense for arguments of modulus less than $1$, but in your case this could be anything (take $b$ close to 1$)

Comment: @Guido - for the case $\int_0^x \cdots dt$

Comment: @Quanto I see. What about the other one?

Comment: @Guido - you would need $\coth^{-1}(\dot)$ instead

Comment: How did you came up with your decomposition?